# Jquery Terminal always focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, terminal, jquery-terminal

I am using the JCubic Jquery Terminal, works great but the cursor is always focused on the terminal cmd.

Any other textfield/textbox on the page does not work because any key press focuses the cursor back on the Terminal.

https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/tree/master/js

I assume there's an answer in the *jquery.terminal-1.3.1.j*s file. But where?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible solutions involve `onBlur`, `keydown`, `keypress` handlers in your `options` you pass when you create the terminal - there could be others, there's a **LOT** of [options in the DOCUMENTATION](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php)

Comment: Do you use `onBlur: fuction() { return false; }` like in demos that are full screen? This prevent loosing focus.

Comment: do you have a demo online?

Comment: Hey! Glad to see the project is so active. I can definitely make a demo, how can I message you the login details? also, it shows "onBlur: e.noop"

Comment: I fixed it by changing any onBlur from false to true. not sure if that's the smartest way though!!

Comment: Hey guys, I have been facing the same issue . Could you elaborate on how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around that by returning from `keypress` and `keydown` handlers when target is an `input`:

```
return $(this.context).terminal( () => {}, {
    keypress        : (e, terminal) => {
        if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
                return true;
        }
        // ...
    },

    keydown         : (evt, terminal) => {
        if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
                return true;
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
});
```